# OperationalError: near "System": syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e63de1bbf3b5> in <module>()

      1 for row in df.iterrows():
      2        sql = 'INSERT INTO salesdata ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(df.columns), ','.join(['?']*len(df.columns)))
----> 3        c.execute(sql, tuple(row[1]))
      4 conn.commit()
```

I get OperationalError: near "System": syntax error . I tried inserting more space and removing space between single quotes it does not work. How do I make this code work?

Comment: I'd suggest logging both the literal content of the `sql` string and of the tuple being passed as arguments. Right now there's not enough to go on included in this question. (I'm assuming `System` is one of your dataframe's column names, but it'd be better to have a standalone [mre] and not need to assume).

Comment: `SYSTEM` is a reserved word in MySQL 8.0. You need to put it in backticks.

Comment: You should use the [DBAPI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) to insert parameters, not string formatting.

Comment: @Keith, ...though in this case, they're using string formatting to insert column names and `?` placeholders for DBAPI to use. Seeing `.format()` in there gave me a similar knee-jerk reaction, and it *is* at the root of their problem insofar as they did a worse job of it than, say, SQLAlchemy would... but the OP isn't coming from an entirely bad place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably one of your column names is `System`. This is a reserved word in MySQL 8.0, so it needs to be escaped. You should surround all the column names with backticks.

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO salesdata ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(','.join('`' + col + '`' for col in df.columns), ','.join(['?']*len(df.columns)))
```